# What are my rights with regarding privacy at Maccas drive through?

Tags: privacy, australia

I have been informed that some of Maccas drive throughs are starting to use cameras with number plate recognition software, provided by  https://summitinnovations.com/.

What are my rights to privacy in Australia? Who can access this information? Where is this information stored? Why am I not informed of this when I enter the drive through so that I can make an informed privacy decision? Does this fall under the remit of the OAIC? And can the police obtain access to this information? And finally is this information sold?

Comment: Re: *"I have been informed..."* by whom? Can you cite your source, please?

Comment: Re: *"Why am I not informed of this when I enter..."* Maybe you visit locations that doesn't use this tech (as only *"some"* do).